# RequestMapping with annotation vs parameter

Tags: java, performance, model-view-controller, annotations

I am thinking about a general RequestMapping question. Without choosing any specific MVC framework, comparing the annotation based request mapping to a simple parameter checker mapping, which is the better?

Lets say I want to create a web service, which should handle for example an "add" and a "remove" operation.

Using annotations it would look something like this:

```
@Path("/add")
public void add(String addable) {}

@Path("/remove")
public void remove(String deletable) {}
```

Using parameter it would look like this:

```
@Path("/operation")
public void doOperation(Operation op) {
    String type = op.getType();
    if ("add".equals(type)) {
        add(op);
    } else if ("remove".equals(type)) {
        remove(op);
    }
}
```

In the second example, lets say Operation object is built from a JSON object. So the idea is that we have only a general Operation, which has a type parameter and we always calling the same request (/operation in this case) and the actual request type is inside the JSON object.

I know the first one looks better, but is there any other reason why it is a better solution? It has better performance or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- There shouldn't be any significant performance difference.
- The first code is much more readable
- You have to pass extra parameter all the time for the second solution

Your question can be simplified to this case:

```
class A {
 methodA()
 methodB()
}

class B {
 methodC(Operation) {
    check what operation there is and invoke the needed method.
 }
}
```

You would go with class B in cases where you don't want to give direct access to other methods or if you want to make extra work before invoking methodA() or methodB(). For example, authenticate user.

In MVC frameworks you have already other tools to do that.